# React CSSTransition not respecting transition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There have been some questions on CSSTransition of React TransitionGroup library. However, I can't fix my problem.

Here is the code sandbox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-firefly-gbifmw

#### Problem

If you click on the first row with text `name` in it, there will be a dropdown shown. The dropdown is defined in `src/components/Dropdown/Dropdown.js`. Now I wrapped this dropdown using CSSTransition in the file `src/components/Tab/Tab.js`. My expectation is that it transition smoothly from `opacity:0` to `opacity:1` on `enter` and vice-versa on `exit`.

Now in my `src/components/Dropdown/dropdown.css`, I defined the `enter, enter-active, enter-done, exit, exit-active, exit-done` class. However, the animation is behaving strangely: When clicked to open, it will blink once. And when clicked to close, it will disappear without animation.

#### Previous Research

I have read in some posts saying that I need to attach a `transition:<property> <duration> <function>` to the main class. In this case, it should be the `dropdown-wrapper` class. Currently I'm doing this and the animation is acting strange.

If I remove the `transition` in class`dropdown-wrapper`, the animation will completely go away. But it shouldn't, since for example, here is one that doesn't have a `transition` attached to the **main class**:

https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-bas-mjgbqg?file=/index.js

I think the `in` attribute of CSSTransition is working fine since I can toggle the dropdown. I also added a `unmountOnExit`.

Any inputs are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Your first codesandbox link refused to install the dependencies for me, but after testing your second codesandbox link, I was able to fix the flashing issue by upgrading react-transition-group from 4.4.4 to 4.4.5.

Possibly related to the use of unmountOnExit that was fixed here: https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/pull/847

Comment: I was thinking that the second link works fine originally?